# How could I acomplish having a single instance of an object per compiled program/dynamic library?

Tags: c++, c++17, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am working on a file system watcher for a large application. The original version had a watch thread run for every instance of my `FileSystemWatcher` class. However that creates way too many threads.

The application consists of many DLL "plugins" that each statically link the basic library where my file system watcher class is:

[image]

Now these DLLs may not share a thread for filesystem watching (they might not even be compiled with the exact same version of the library), but each of those plugins, `a.dll` and `b.dll` in the picture, should have a single thread for all requests for filesystem watching. I can deal with the implementation, but what I don't know is how to have a single instance for each dll.

The idea is to have a singleton, but have one instance of the variable per dll:

```
class FileSystemWatcherManager
{
public:
  static FileSystemWatcherManager* Instance()
  {
    // How to make it single instance per dll?
    static FileSystemWatcherManager instance;
    return &instance;
  }
};
```

How can it be accomplished?

Comment: Are you strictly on Windows and using DLLs? If so, the default behaviour of `static` class members which are not `dllexport`ed should match what you want. The situation is different when ELF-style `.so` enters the picture.

Comment: The application is windows only, but if you can answer the question for Linux, that may be useful to other people googling this problem. I had little luck googling this even though I suspected that static in a CPP file would suffice, which is why I asked.

Comment: Why do you want to statically link it? I mean, as long as you use it from behind an interface you can have watcher in common dll, right?

Comment: @bartop As said in the question, different modules may have been compiled with slightly different versions of the utility library. Linking the library dynamically would then require binary compatibility to a higher degree. Same approach is taken with c++ stdlib, which is also not in a separate dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, if a static storage duration variable is not `dllexport`ed, each DLL and EXE file will have its own copy of it. So just make sure that neither `FileSystemWatcherManager` nor `FileSystemWatcherManager::Instance` are exported from the DLL, and you should get the behaviour you want.